# Help interpreting question about a system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm currently working through Beckenbach and Bellman's book "An Introduction to Inequalities." One of the questions has me a little stumped, as I'm not really sure what they're asking for.

For fixed $a, b, m$, and $n$, solve the system of equations:

$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ and

$mx + ny = k$

choosing $k$ so that the resulting quadratic equation has a double root. I know how to solve a system of equations, but I'm not entirely sure what they're asking for here. I'm not really sure how I'd even end up with a factorable quadratic. Maybe just add the two together and try to factor?

Any help appreciated. Preferably in hint form. I'd rather not have the solution entirely spoiled.

p.s. I know what a double root is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that by the resulting quadratic the meaning is this: when you solve (e.g) $y$ from the lower equation and plug it in the first you get a quadratic in one variable.

Now these equations represent an ellipse and a line. It's nice to think it geometrically too.

EDIT: My calculations. Hope there are no errors.

$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ and $mx + ny = k$

Assume $n\neq 0$. Then $y = \frac{k}{n} - \frac{m}{n}x$ and

$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{(\frac{k}{n} - \frac{m}{n}x)^2}{b^2}=1 $$
$$ (\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{m^2}{b^2n^2})x^2-\frac{2 k m}{b^2n^2} x +\frac{k^2}{b^2 n^2}-1= 0 $$

For this to have double root, the discriminant must be zero:

$$\frac{4 k^2 m^2}{b^4n^4} - 4(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{m^2}{b^2n^2})(\frac{k^2}{b^2 n^2}-1) =0 $$

$$ (\frac{4 m^2}{b^4n^4} - \frac{4(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{m^2}{b^2n^2})}{b^2 n^2}) k^2 + 4(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{m^2}{b^2n^2}) =0 $$

Solving this for $k$ gives

$$ |k| =\sqrt{\frac{4(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{m^2}{b^2n^2})}{\frac{4(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{m^2}{b^2n^2})}{b^2 n^2}-\frac{4 m^2}{b^4n^4} }}  = \sqrt{\frac{(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{m^2}{b^2n^2})} {\frac{\frac{1}{a^2}}{b^2 n^2}+\frac{m^2}{b^4 n^4}-\frac{ m^2}{b^4n^4} }}$$

$$=\frac {\sqrt{(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{m^2}{b^2n^2})}}{\frac{1}{abn}} = \sqrt{a^2m^2+b^2n^2}$$

Comment: Ok, after reading through this, the problem makes much more sense. For some reason, I never thought to think about what the discriminant would have to be. It didn't help that the wording confused me either.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$x = \verts{a}\cos\pars{\theta}$ and $y = \verts{b}\sin\pars{\theta}$ satisfy the ellipse equation. So
$$
m\braces{\verts{a}\cos\pars{\theta}} + n\braces{\verts{b}\sin\pars{\theta}} = k
\quad\imp\quad
\sin\pars{\theta} + {m\verts{a} \over n\verts{b}}\,\cos\pars{\theta}
= {k \over n\verts{b}}
$$

> Let's $\ds{\tan\pars{\mu} = {m\verts{a} \over n\verts{b}}}$:
>   $$\!\!\!\!\!
> \sin\pars{\theta}\cos\pars{\mu} + \cos\pars{\theta}\sin\pars{\mu}
> = {k \over n\verts{b}}\,\cos\pars{\mu}
> = {k \over n\verts{b}}\,{1 \over \root{\tan^{2}\pars{\mu} + 1}}
> ={k\sgn\pars{n} \over \root{m^{2}a^{2} + n^{2}b^{2}}}
> $$

$$
\sin\pars{\theta + \mu} = {k\sgn\pars{n} \over \root{m^{2}a^{2} + n^{2}b^{2}}}
$$

> If $\ds{{\verts{k} \over \root{m^{2}a^{2} + n^{2}b^{2}}}  \leq 1}$ we have solutions for $\theta\ \in\ {\mathbb R}$ $\pars{~\mbox{otherwise,}\ \theta\ \in\ {\mathbb C}~}$:
>   $$
> \theta = -\arctan\pars{m\verts{a} \over n\verts{b}} + \arcsin\pars{{k\sgn\pars{n} \over \root{m^{2}a^{2} + n^{2}b^{2}}}}
> + 2\pi n\,,\quad n\ \in\ {\mathbb Z}
> $$
>   where $0 \leq \arcsin\pars{\alpha} < 2\pi$
>
> Once we know $\theta$ we can evaluate $x = \verts{a}\cos\pars{\theta}$ and
>   $y = \verts{b}\sin\pars{\theta}$:
>   \begin{align}
> x&=\verts{a}\cos\pars{\arctan\pars{m\verts{a} \over n\verts{b}}}
> \cos\pars{\arcsin\pars{k\sgn\pars{n} \over \root{m^{2}a^{2} + n^{2}b^{2}}}}
> \\[3mm]&+
> \verts{a}\sin\pars{\arctan\pars{m\verts{a} \over n\verts{b}}}
> \sin\pars{\arcsin\pars{k\sgn\pars{n} \over \root{m^{2}a^{2} + n^{2}b^{2}}}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \verts{a}\,{1 \over \root{\pars{ma/nb}^{2} + 1}}\,
> \root{1 - {k^{2} \over m^{2}a^{2} + n^{2}b^{2}}}
> \\[3mm]&+
> \verts{a}\,{m\verts{a}/\pars{n\verts{b}} \over \root{\pars{ma/nb}^{2} + 1}}\,
> {k\sgn\pars{n} \over \root{m^{2}a^{2} + n^{2}b^{2}}}
> \end{align}

$$
\color{#00f}{\large%
\begin{array}{rcl}
x & = &
{\verts{nba}\sqrt{m^{2}a^{2} + n^{2}b^{2} - k^{2}} + ma^{2}k \over m^{2}a^{2} + n^{2}b^{2}}
\\[3mm]
y & = & {k \over n} - {m \over n}\,x
\\[3mm]&&
\color{#000}{\large\mbox{when}\
{\verts{k} \over \root{m^{2}a^{2} + n^{2}b^{2}}} \leq 1}
\end{array}}
$$